# Deterministically secure PRG from deterministically secure OWF

Tags: randomness, pseudo-random-generator, one-way-function

Consider the construction of "A Pseudorandom Generator from any One-way Function" [[HILL99]](https://www.csc.kth.se/%7Ejohanh/prgfromowf.pdf) in Hastad et al.

One way to proof pseudorandomness of this construction is by contradiction.
That is, an assumed PRG distinguisher is transformed into a OWF inverter (usually through an intermediate notion called pseudoentropy generator).
There is both a uniform and a non-uniform version, considering uniform resp. non-uniform distinguishers/inverters.
However, in all proofs of the uniform version that I have seen the PRG distinguisher and the OWF inverter are *randomized*.

Is it (im-)possible to convert a deterministic (uniform) PRG distinguisher into a deterministic (uniform) OWF inverter?